# Why does setState work parsing each key individually, but not as an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am learning react and typescript and I am unable to pass an object with a type to set an state. The state simply does not update.

I am using useForm() hook in order to create a type that has 3 values, and when I click submit, it should update the state.

This is the state:

```
  const [personalInfo,setPersonalInfo] = useState<PersonalData>( {
    name: "juan",
    email: "whatever",
    about: "blabla"
  });
```

If I use

```
  const handlePersonalInfo = (data:PersonalData) => {
    const newState = data;
    setPersonalInfo(newState);
    console.log(personalInfo);   
  };
```

the state will only update the first time. Any subsequent calls to this function wont work, yet it will log the object in the console,

On the contrary, if I get every key of the parameter and assign it inidividually, it updates:

```
const handlePersonalInfo = (data:PersonalData) => {
    const newState = data;
    setPersonalInfo({name:data.name,email:data.email,about:data.about});
    console.log(personalInfo);
    
  };
```

I am a little bit conduse and I am 99% sure there is a better way to do this

Thank you for any tips on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, the code calling `handlePersonalInfo` is *modifying* the properties on the `personalInfo` object it's getting from `useState` (*mutating* the object state). It shouldn't do that, you must treat state objects as though their properties were readonly; [more in the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state). When you do that, React doesn't see any state change because the code is just modifying the values of the properties, not creating a new object.

Your code where you create a new object works because you're creating a new object. But that's a workaround rather than a solution. :-) To properly solve the problem, find the code that's directly mutating the state of the `personalInfo` object and have *that* code create a new object instead. You want to do that because code directly mutating the object that doesn't call `handlePersonalInfo` may cause strange UI issues to creep up when React rerenders your component because of changes to *other* state members.

As an example, it sounds like you have code that looks something like this:

```
personalInfo.name = "Carlos";
handlePersonalInfo(personalInfo);
```

Instead, that should do this at a minimum:

```
handlePersonalInfo({...personalInfo, name: "Carlos"});
```

...although even that may not work quite correctly since `personalInfo` could be stale. Since the `handlePersonalInfo` function in the question doesn't do anything more than `setPersonalInfo` (and loggign), the code would be best off calling `setPersonalInfo` directly and using the callback form:

```
setPersonalInfo((previous) => ({...previous, name: "Carlos"}));
```

Here's an example of doing it incorrectly:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [personalInfo,setPersonalInfo] = useState({
        name: "juan",
        email: "whatever",
        about: "blabla"
    });
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const doSomething = () => {
        // >>>INCORRECT<<<
        // This is a direct mutation
        personalInfo.name = "Carlos";
        setPersonalInfo(personalInfo);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Name: {personalInfo.name}{" "}
                <input type="button" value="Update" onClick={doSomething} />
            </div>
            <div>Email: {personalInfo.email}</div>
            <div>About: {personalInfo.about}</div>
            <div>
                Counter: {counter}{" "}
                <input type="button" value="+" onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

To see why direct mutation is a problem, run that and click the **Update** button. Notice that "juan" doesn't change to "Carlos". But then click the **+** button to increment the counter (completely unrelated state). Voila! It says "Carlos"!

Instead, create the new object when setting the name, never assign directly:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [personalInfo,setPersonalInfo] = useState({
        name: "juan",
        email: "whatever",
        about: "blabla"
    });
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const doSomething = () => {
        // Correct version:
        setPersonalInfo((previous) => ({...previous, name: "Carlos"}));
        // May work in some cases with certain events (like "click"):
        // setPersonalInfo({...personalInfo, name: "Carlos"});
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Name: {personalInfo.name}{" "}
                <input type="button" value="Update" onClick={doSomething} />
            </div>
            <div>Email: {personalInfo.email}</div>
            <div>About: {personalInfo.about}</div>
            <div>
                Counter: {counter}{" "}
                <input type="button" value="+" onClick={() => setCounter((c) => c + 1)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

That updates when you click **Update**, as it should.

Comment: Ty for the quick answer! 

I am using the useForm() hook (which I think is not entirely supported by react) in order to get the values from a form and then I use the handleSubmit function in order to call `onSubmitHandler` :

`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>`
this calls
```const onSubmitHandler = (values: PersonalData) => {    
        const newval = values;
        props.setFunction(newval); 
    }
```
I guess your suggestion is instead of :
`const newval = values;`
assign each of the values manually ? 
`const newval = {values.name,values.email,values.about };` ?

Comment: @JuanLuque - Refer to the documentation for whatever `useForm` hook you're using. From what you've shown above, it looks like it's directly modifying the object you give it and then giving you back the same object (with modified properties), which would be incorrect. That suggests you're supposed to do something different elsewhere, in code you haven't shown (where you're giving the `personalInfo` to the hook). But again, refer to that hook's documentation for how to use it, I'm having to guess at things here.

Comment: Im navigating other apporaches, but in case you still would like to ahve a look sometime:  https://github.com/jcluq/CoolForm